# Unable to perform Ignite SQL query over [CustomKey, CustomValue] cache in Scala.

Tags: java, sql, scala, ignite

I am trying to setup a distributed cache using Apache Ignite with Scala. 
After setting up the cache, I am able to put and get items knowing the key, but SQL queries of any type returns always a cursor with null iterator.

Here is how I setup my cache (please note that this is done before the ignition.start):

```
def setupTelemetryCache(): CacheConfiguration[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue] = {

val dataRegionName = "persistent-region"
val cacheName = "telemetry-cache"

// This object is required to perform SQL queries over custom key object
val queryEntity = new QueryEntity("TelemetryKey", "TelemetryValue")
val fields: util.LinkedHashMap[String, String] = new util.LinkedHashMap[String, String]
fields.put("deviceId", classOf[String].getName)
fields.put("metricName", classOf[String].getName)
fields.put("timestamp", classOf[String].getName)
queryEntity.setFields(fields)
val keyFields: util.HashSet[String] = new util.HashSet[String]()
keyFields.add("deviceId")
keyFields.add("metricName")
keyFields.add("timestamp")
queryEntity.setKeyFields(keyFields)
queryEntity.setIndexes(Collections.emptyList[QueryIndex]())

new CacheConfiguration()
  .setName(cacheName)
  .setDataRegionName(dataRegionName)
  .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED) // Data is split among nodes
  .setBackups(1) // each partition has 1 backup
  .setIndexedTypes(classOf[String], classOf[TelemetryKey])  // Index by ID
  .setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_ASYNC) // Faster, clients do not wait for cache
  // synchronization. Consistency issues?
  .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL) // Allows transactional query
  .setQueryEntities(Collections.singletonList(queryEntity)) 
}
```

And those are the code of my TelemetryKey:

```
case class TelemetryKey private (
                              @(AffinityKeyMapped @field)
                              @(QuerySqlField@field)(index = true)
                              deviceId: String,
                              @(QuerySqlField@field)(index = false)
                              metricName: String,
                              @(QuerySqlField@field)(index = true)
                              timestamp: String) extends Serializable
```

And TelemetryValue:

```
class TelemetryValue private(valueType: ValueTypes.Value, doubleValue: Option[Double],
                             stringValue: Option[String],
                             longValue: Option[Long]) extends Serializable
```

A sample SQL query I have to achieve could be "Select * from CACHE where deviceId = 'dev1234'" and I expect to receive all the Cache.Entry[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue] of the same deviceId

Here is how I perform the query:

```
 private def sqlQuery(query: SqlQuery[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue]):
  QueryCursor[Cache.Entry[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue]] = {
    cache.query(query)
  }

  def getEntries(ofDeviceId: String):
  QueryCursor[Cache.Entry[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue]] = {
    val q = new SqlQuery[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue](classOf[TelemetryKey], "deviceId = ?")
    sqlQuery(q.setArgs(ofDeviceId))
  }
```

Even changing the body of the query i receive a cursor object which is empty. I cannot even perform a "Select *" query.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to configure indexes and queryable fields.

1. [Annotation based configuration](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes#section-annotation-based-configuration) 
   Your key and value classes need to be annotated `@QuerySqlField` as follows.

```
    case class TelemetryKey private (
    @(AffinityKeyMapped @field)
    @(QuerySqlField@field)(index = true)
    deviceId: String,
    @(QuerySqlField@field)(index = false)
    metricName: String,
    @(QuerySqlField@field)(index = true)
    timestamp: String) extends Serializable
```

After indexed and queryable fields are defined, they have to be registered in the SQL engine along with the object types they belong to.

```
    new CacheConfiguration()
    .setName(cacheName)
    .setDataRegionName(dataRegionName)
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
    .setBackups(1)
    .setIndexedTypes(classOf[TelemetryKey], classOf[TelemetryValue])
    .setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_ASYNC)
    .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
```

**UPD:**
One more thing that should be fixed as well is your `SqlQuery`

```
  def getEntries(ofDeviceId: String):
  QueryCursor[Cache.Entry[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue]] = {
    val q = new SqlQuery[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue](classOf[TelemetryValue], "deviceId = ?")
    sqlQuery(q.setArgs(ofDeviceId))
  }
```

2. [QueryEntity based approach](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes#section-queryentity-based-configuration)

```
val queryEntity = new QueryEntity(classOf[TelemetryKey], classOf[TelemetryValue]);
```

```
    new CacheConfiguration()
    .setName(cacheName)
    .setDataRegionName(dataRegionName)
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
    .setBackups(1)
    .setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_ASYNC)
    .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
    .setQueryEntities(Collections.singletonList(queryEntity))
```

Comment: I tried both solutions. In both cases, when performing the query, the program crashes with javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find SQL table for type: it.agilelab.wasp.iot.telemetry.TelemetryKey


Only in the first approach, if I replace     .setIndexedTypes(classOf[TelemetryKey], classOf[TelemetryValue])
with
    .setIndexedTypes(classOf[String], classOf[TelemetryKey])

The program doesn't crash but the result is empty

Comment: Lets's try the first approach with `setIndexedTypes(classOf[TelemetryKey], classOf[TelemetryValue])` and modify `SqlQuery` as follows: `def getEntries(ofDeviceId: String):
  QueryCursor[Cache.Entry[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue]] = {
    val q = new SqlQuery[TelemetryKey, TelemetryValue](classOf[TelemetryValue], "deviceId = ?")
    sqlQuery(q.setArgs(ofDeviceId))
  }
`

Comment: Damn! Found the issue! It was on the (classOf[TelemetryValue], "deviceId = ?") 
I was using classOf[TelemetryKey]
Now both methods work perfectly
Thank you very much!

let me say that this documentation (of the Ignite SqlQuery) should be revised
`/**
     * Constructs query for the given type and SQL query.
     *
     * @param type Type.
     * @param sql SQL Query.
     */`

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you should supply full JVM class names to QueryEntity.

As in:

```
val queryEntity = new QueryEntity("com.pany.telemetry.TelemetryKey",
    "com.pany.telemetry.TelemetryValue") // or e.g. TelemetryKey.class.getName()
```

Ignite needs these to distinguish various types that can be stored in one cache, it's not decorative - there's got to be an exact match.

Better yet? Use `setIndexedTypes()` instead of `setQueryEntities()`. It allows you to pass classes instead of Strings and it will scan annotations, which you already have.

Comment: In this case, I have the program crashing with the error: 
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find SQL table for type: it.agilelab.wasp.iot.telemetry.TelemetryKey